# CKEditor and Wiki Markup (A Custom Data Processor?)

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, ckeditor, wysiwyg, wiki-markup

I am looking for a non-HTML Rich text editing solution.

Since I do not want to allow users to post HTML code from fear of various XSS reasons I implemented a Wiki Markup solution using [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) which works great.

However, there is a loud demand for a real WYSIWYG Rich Text editing.

I found out that CKEditor [can support external Custom Data Processors](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor) that theoretically can have it work with any markup language.

However, I couldn't find any implementation of such a Custom Processor...

Does anyone knows of such implementation (Wiki Markup or others: MarkDown, BBCode, etc.)?
Does anyone know of any other solution to the situation?

I would prefer a client side only solution but an Ajax based converter using a .Net based converter is also acceptable.

Thanks!

Comment: A basic BBCode plugin is available in the CKEditor package: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/bbcode.html

Comment: This actually looks pretty good, post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic BBCode plugin is available in the CKEditor package: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/bbcode.html